how to add picture to vscode titlebar
I currentl have a title bar that looks like this with code
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#a8a06b",
    "titleBar.activeForeground": "#ebdbb2",
    "titleBar.inactiveBackground": "#282828",
    "titleBar.inactiveForeground": "#928374"
  },


I want to add image overlays to it looks something like this
I see that this is possible in google chrome here

How can we override the background image inside the vscode software?
